# React JS Context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Hello everyone I'm making a website for selling clothes, I started adding a feature to add products to the cart. On the product page I have buttons for choosing the size and color, and a button for adding an item to the cart. Here's what the button looks like in the code:

```
<div className="model__info-add-cart">
  <button type="button" className="add-cart__button" onClick={() => onAdd(ProductData, color, size, 1)}>
    Add to Cart
  </button>
</div>
```

StateContext.js file:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast';

const Context = createContext();

export const StateContext = ({ children }) => {
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
    const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(0);
    const [color, setColor] = useState();
    const [size, setSize] = useState();
    const [totalQuantities, setTotalQuantities] = useState(0);
    const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);

    const onAdd = (product, color, size, quantity) => {
        const checkProductInCart = cartItems.find((item) => item._id === product._id && item.color === color && item.size === size);
        setTotalPrice((prevTotalPrice) => prevTotalPrice + product.price * quantity);
        setTotalQuantities((prevTotalQuantities) => prevTotalQuantities + quantity);

        if (checkProductInCart) {
            const updateCartItems = cartItems.map((cartProduct) => {
                if (cartProduct._id === product._id) return {
                    ...cartProduct,
                    quantity: cartProduct.quantity + quantity
                }

            })
            setCartItems(updateCartItems);
        } else {
            product.quantity = quantity;
            product.color = color;
            product.size = size; 
            setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...product }])
        }
    }

    const SetSize = (Size) => {
        setSize(Size);
    }
    const SetColor = (Color) => {
        setColor(Color);
    }

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={{ cartItems, totalPrice, color, size, totalQuantities, qty, SetSize, SetColor, onAdd }}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(Context);
```

When I click add to cart, everything is fine, but when I go to another product page, the data about the previous product in the cart is lost

Any help would be greatly appreciated.